# What is the name for the "<<<" operator?

Tags: php, syntax

I know this is going to be straight forward but its also impossible to search for...

what is the correct term / name for this 3 arrow thing - e.g.

```
<<< HTML
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> 

A third way to delimit [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)s is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

> 

The closing identifier *must* begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

> > 

**Warning** It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier *may not be indented*, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is *\n* on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

> > 

If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.

> > 

Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties. Since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables...

Comment: +1.  Not often is a one word answer acceptable (unless it's "No!") :)

Answer (score 0):

you can see this manual [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)