# 'END' keyword in switch case?

Tags: php, syntax, case, switch-statement

so I'm looking at another person's code trying to fix it, and I'm not sure what is happening.  I have a pretty strong knowledge of programming in general, but there is one line that is throwing me off. See below:

```
<?php
switch ($task) {
    case "createDJ":
          echo <<<END;
          <h5>Create DJ Form</h5>
          <!-- Code for DJ form goes here. -->
          END;
          break;
    case "createShow":
         echo <<<END;
         <h5>Create Show Form</h5>
         <!-- Code for Show form goes here. -->
         END;
         break;
   //...
?>
```

What is going on with these `END` statements?  I've never seen them before, Also, what is up with the `<<<` sign?

EDIT: Sorry about the syntax highlighting, not sure why it's all messy.

EDIT: And now I understand why the syntax highlighting is messed up! haha

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the name for the "<<<" operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062830/what-is-the-name-for-the-operator)

Comment: you are sure, that you formatted it right? `END;` is the end of the heredoc-statement started with `<<<END`, but it _must_ stand at the beginning of the line, or the script fails

Comment: yeah, it's someone else's code and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work.  Thank you though for the insight. :)

Comment: You failed to look at the PHP manual.

Comment: This is true, but I did google around a bit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a statement, it's a way of quoting a string.

It's called called heredoc syntax, and it's supposed to be a convenient way to quote a multi-line string. `<<<END` starts it and `END` at the beginning of a line ends it. (`END` is the programmer's choice, they can use an identifier they want.)

This is explained [here in the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: `<<<`. After this
>   operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself
>   follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier ***must*** begin in the first column of the line.
>   Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other
>   label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc.

Comment: Worth to note: It's called "heredoc". You can create multiline-strings with _any_ string-syntax

Answer (score 1):

It's the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax for strings, available in a couple of languages.

```
<<<HERE
string text here
HERE
```