# php operator <<<

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the name for the “<<<” operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062830/what-is-the-name-for-the-operator)

I've just seen this code on this website:

[PHP for Beginners: Building Your First Simple CMS](http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/)

The code is:

```
private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
            title       VARCHAR(150),
            bodytext    TEXT,
            created     VARCHAR(100)
    )
    MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I've search high and low for this operand "<<<" but I can't seem to find the documentation anywhere!

If this operand is *real* I would like to know how it works because writing SQL queries like this makes code much more readable and would make SQL bugs simpler to find!

Might i add that i tried this code and got a compile error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Users\Alex Morley-Finch\Dropbox\Shared\Projects\htdocs\test\php\database.php on line 121
```

Comment: thankyou! i didnt realise it was a duplicate as i didnt know it was a called a HEREDOC! voting to close

Answer (score 5):

In the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), the last line (the one with the closing identifier) can't be indented, you have to do this:

```
<?php
       private function buildDB() {
$sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
     title       VARCHAR(150),
     bodytext    TEXT,
     created     VARCHAR(100)
)
MySQL_QUERY;

              return mysql_query($sql);
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and you need to make sure that the ending line starts at the beginning of the line, so no:

```
    MySQL_QUERY;
```

but:

```
MySQL_QUERY;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<<` is a HEREDOC.  You can read about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).  The most important thing to remember when using it is that the last line must not have any spaces.