# please explain this PHP code "<<<CSS"

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [What is the name for the “<<<” operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062830/what-is-the-name-for-the-operator)

I can infer what this is doing but I need to know how, and possible find some documentation.
The expression in the title `<<<CSS` seems to set up a block of css to be inserted into a template. However there are no functions to strip the `<<<CSS` from these text strings yet they do not appear. This leads me to believe that `<<<` is not just a random marker but has special PHP meaning. Please help.

```
if(!empty($background['header_image'])){
    $header_image = <<<CSS
background-image: url('{$background['header_image']}');
background-repeat: {$background['header_repeat']};
background-position: top {$background['header_position_x']};
background-attachment: scroll;
CSS;`
```

Comment: I tried searching for '“<<<” operator' both in google and this forum. Try yourself. I tried "3 less-than" etc. etc. etc.. I really tried before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called heredoc. See the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

It's an easy way to assign multiple lines of text to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a heredoc: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3

Basically, it says "insert into this string everything after <<<CSS until you find CSS on a line by itself."